# Proof by induction of the volume of an n-dimensional box

Tags: induction, volume

To solve a question I need a formula for the volume of an n-dimensional box with edges parallel to the coordinate axes centred at the origin. I am attempting to use induction. I am not entirely sure this is the correct way to approach. However, it is the only method I could think of.
$$V(n)=\prod_{i=1}^n2x_i, n=2: V(2)=2^2x_1x_2$$
By observation we can see V(2) is true. Assuming the induction hypothesis that for an arbitrary k, the singular case n=k holds, meaning V(k) is true.
$$V(k)=\prod_{i=1}^k2x_i=2^k(x_1x_2...x_k)$$
It follows that:
$$V(k+1)=2^{k+1}(x_1x_2...x_kx_{k+1})=2^k(x_1x_2...x_k)2x_{k+1}$$
I am unsure of how to proceed here. I do not believe I can finish by saying $V(k+1)=2V(k)x_{k+1}$.

Comment: What's your definition of volume?

Comment: For n=3, $V=8x_1x_2x_3$. The $2^3$ is due to the fact I am specifying the coordinates of a vertex of the box, so it is necessary to double each coordinate to find the true length of each edge.

Comment: What about general $n$? The reason why I ask is because if I only know what volume means for $n=3$, how in the world will I know how to compute the volume in $n=4$?

Comment: The definition of a volume for an n-dimensional rectangular box centred at the origin is stated above. I am unsure as to what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

The volume of an $n$-dimensional rectangular box $B =[a_1,b_1] \times \dots \times [a_n,b_n]$ is *defined* as
$$V(B)  =\prod_{i=1}^n (b_i -a_i) .$$

In your case you have $a_i = -x_i, b_i = x_i$. Thus $b_i - a_i = 2x_i$ and
$$V = \prod_{i=1}^n (2x_i) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n 2\right)\left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right) = 2^n \prod_{i=1}^n x_i.$$

Comment: I am aware of the formula, however I wish to prove this by induction for use in a problem. If you could provide insight on how to do this that would be great!

Comment: You can use induction to get your result from this formula. The base case is easy, and take out a factor in the product and apply the inductive hypothesis

Comment: That is what I have tried to do above. Forgive my ignorance on the topic, I am still new to proof writing as I am a student of physics not mathematics.

Comment: @benmcgloin I edited my answer. I do not think we need a formal induction proof for the last equation (although you can of course do that), it is really obvious and follows from the commutativity of multiplication.